# Apache htaccess .phps?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

So I want the user to be able to run write "foo.phps" for a "foo.php" script in order to present the source of that file.

I only want to do this in one directory (since it's a security risk). Can I use .htaccess?

I added a .htaccess file to the directory and wrote this in it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

And then restarted Apache, but I can't add "s" to the file to get the source. Do I need to do something with PHP as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php), you need to use a `SetHandler`

```
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if you can use a directive in a .htaccess in general, you can always consult the documentation. For Apache 2.0, see:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype

```
Description: Maps the given filename extensions onto the specified content type
Syntax:      AddType MIME-type extension [extension] ...
Context:     server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess
Override:    FileInfo
Status:      Base
Module:      mod_mime
```

In particular look at the "Context:" part.

In this specific case, yes, you can. You just need to make sure you allow overrides for FileInfo on that particular directory:

e.g.

```
<Directory /path/to/my/site>
    AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
```

You also need to make sure the file EXISTS. If you have a file called test.php you can't just magically request test.phps

In order to solve that problem, you can either use mod_rewrite to force a handler. For example, this rule is in the mod_rewrite documentation as a good example of changing the handler in mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(/source/.+\.php)s$ $1 [H=application/x-httpd-php-source]
```

or you could create a symbolic link but you will need to do that for every file manually (or script it) and for new files.

```
ln -s test.php test.phps
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is you will need an additional script 
that simply outputs the source of the specified file.
Then you can write a rewrite rule to rewrite

- foo.phps

into

- showmethesource.php?input=foo.php

One MAJOR issue with this is security.
Make sure you can only output the desired files and not any file (like /etc/passwd) !!

Comment: Why use a potentially vulnerable script when there's built-in functionality to do it safely?